# Find n logarithmic intervals between two end points

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find n logarithmic intervals between two numbers.

eg: for a function 
logDiv (10, 10000, 3) where 10 is the starting point, 10000 the ending point, and 3 the number of intervals, I would like to get the following output:
(* {10, 100, 1000, 10000} *)

What I have tried:

```
function logInterval(total_intervals, start, end) {
   var index, interval, result = [];
    for (index = 0; index < total_intervals; index++) {
      interval = (index/total_intervals * Math.log((end - start) + 1) - 1 + start);
        result.push(interval);
    }
    return result;
}
var intervals = logInterval(5, 1, 500);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qxqxwo3z/

This was based on my (poor) understanding of the following solution I found in stack exchange mathematica:

```
logspace [increments_, start_, end_] := Module[{a}, (
   a = Range[0, increments];
   Exp[a/increments*Log[(end - start) + 1]] - 1 + start
)]
```

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13226/how-can-i-get-exactly-5-logarithmic-divisions-of-an-interval

Please can someone help me with this? Its not necessary to follow any of my above attempts, just explaining what I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the above answer by nina and a lot more googling and stack overflow answers, I found that this works for me:

```
function logInterval(total_intervals, start, end) {
     var startInterVal = 1, endInterval = total_intervals,
         minLog = Math.log(start), maxLog = Math.log(end),
         scale = (maxLog-minLog) / (endInterval-startInterVal),
         result = [];


      for (i = 1; i < total_intervals; i++) {
          result.push(Math.exp(minLog + scale*(i - startInterVal)));
      }
      result.push(end);
      return result;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qxqxwo3z/1/

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to start with the logarithmic difference of the end value and the start value, divided by the intervals.

```
x = (Math.log(end) - Math.log(start)) / total_intervals;
```

For the factor, you need to do the reverse operation

```
factor = Math.exp(x);
```

For getting an array you can multiply the start value with the factor and insert it into the array. The next value is the last value multiplied by the factor, until all items are generated.

```js
function logInterval(total_intervals, start, end) {
    var x = (Math.log(end) - Math.log(start)) / total_intervals,
        factor = Math.exp(x),
        result = [start],
        i;

    for (i = 1; i < total_intervals; i++) {
        result.push(result[result.length - 1] * factor);
    }
    result.push(end);
    return result;
}

console.log(logInterval(3, 10, 10000));
console.log(logInterval(5, 1, 500));
console.log(logInterval(12, 220, 440)); // some frequencies
```

Comment: It is good except for the fact that the last one is not part of the logarithmic scale, for 5, 1, 500 I get 144.23 and 500 as the last two

Comment: i get `144.2699905907214` and `500`. the first and the last items are always the given values.

Comment: I found a better solution, though yours did help me think in the right direction: https://jsfiddle.net/qxqxwo3z/1/ Thanks for the answer!